# My SQL Auto_increment not working for a fixed column

Tags: mysql, sql, auto-increment

I am trying to create three tables using MySQL Workbench, where two columns need to be auto incremented with a fixed starting value. I have checked some online resources and figured it out what statements to use.

```
create database test;
use test;

/*table Project */
create table Project(
Pnumber INT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
Pname varchar(30) NOT NULL,
Plocation enum ('QLD', 'VIC', 'NSW', 'SA') NOT NULL,
primary key(Pnumber)
);

ALTER TABLE Project AUTO_INCREMENT = 7777770;

/*table Department*/
Create table Department(
Dcode varchar(5) NOT NULL,
Dname varchar(30),
Dmg_ssn varchar(30),
primary key(Dcode)
);

/* Table Employee*/
create table Employee(
Ssn INT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
Ename varchar(30) NOT NULL,
Bdate DATE,
Address varchar(30),
Dcode varchar(5) NOT NULL,
Driver_License varchar(30),
primary key(Ssn),
foreign key(Dcode) references Department(Dcode)
);

ALTER TABLE Employee AUTO_INCREMENT = 1000000;

/* Insert into Project*/
Insert into Project values ('7777770','Star', 'QLD');
Insert into Project values ('7777771','Innova', 'NSW');
Insert into Project values ('7777772','Andra', "QLD");

/* Insert into Department */
insert into Department values ('ABC12', 'Finances', 'RA12');
insert into Department values ('WXY10', 'Human Resources', 'RA12');
insert into Department values ('PBC32', 'S2', 'RB13');

/*Insert into Employee */
insert into Employee values ('0000001','Vladimir Rostov', '2008-7-04', '19 Wilson St', 'ABC12', '1023456');
insert into Employee values ('0000002','Rory Reid', '2002-2-10', '10 Mary St', 'WXY10', '2365947');
insert into Employee values ('0000003','Andy Murray', '2001-5-11', '1280 Albert St', 'WXY10', '5891655');
```

However, after I created the tables, only the column Pnumber in table `Project` follows the required format, while the column Ssn in `Employee` does not.

This is a SELECT over the `Employee` table:

```
Ssn,Ename,Bdate,Address,Dcode,Driver_License
1,"Vladimir Rostov",2008-07-04,"19 Wilson St",ABC12,1023456
2,"Rory Reid",2002-02-10,"10 Mary St",WXY10,2365947
3,"Andy Murray",2001-05-11,"1280 Albert St",WXY10,5891655
```

Any idea what I am doing wrong??

Comment: I wouldn't use AI for this. Despite its name, the feature exists only to ensure that values are unique and sequential (but not necessarily consecutive). AI values should have no meaning beyond the scope of the database.

Comment: Please in code questions give a [mre]--cut & paste & runnable code, including smallest representative example input as code; desired & actual output (including verbatim error messages); tags & versions; clear specification & explanation. Give the least code you can that is code that you show is OK extended by code that you show is not OK. (Debugging fundamental.) For SQL that includes DBMS & DDL (including constraints & indexes) & input as code in table format. [ask] Pause work on the overall goal, chop code to the 1st expression not giving what you expect & say what you expect & why.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your sql script has an `employee` table, not a `student`, I assume these two names refer to the same table. I will use the `employee` name.

So, you set the start value auto increment of the `employee` table to 1000000:

```
ALTER TABLE Employee AUTO_INCREMENT = 1000000;
```

But then you explicitly insert 1, 2, and 3 into this column with your insert statements because `'0000001'` translates into `1`. If you explicitly insert a value into auto increment and it is higher than the maximum value in the given field, then mysql will insert that value as is into the auto increment field.

If you are using auto increment, then you should let it work and do not specify an explicit value:

```
/*Insert into Employee */
insert into Employee (Ename, Bdate, Address, Dcode, Driver_License) values ('Vladimir Rostov', '2008-7-04', '19 Wilson St', 'ABC12', '1023456');
insert into Employee (Ename, Bdate, Address, Dcode, Driver_License) values ('Rory Reid', '2002-2-10', '10 Mary St', 'WXY10', '2365947');
insert into Employee (Ename, Bdate, Address, Dcode, Driver_License) values ('Andy Murray', '2001-5-11', '1280 Albert St', 'WXY10', '5891655');
```